# Is it possible to simulate taking screenshot from iOS Simulator device?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xctest

Using: XCode 14.3.1, XCTest, XCode IOS Simulator

I need to check my application's reaction on attempt of taking screenshot on IOS Simulator. That should be done in autotest, not manually.

Seems to be impossible even to press VolumeUp button on Simulator, which is required for taking screenshot.

Is there any way to simulate this event?